# eager_load crashes boot up in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

eager_load = true will crash the application on boot up. This has been tested on both my local machine and server trying to boot in production. Setting eager_load to false will fix the problem but i would like to have eager load on.

I've checked the stack trace, nothing like undefined variables can be seen. I put eagerload to true in development and it works which is the strange thing.

I went through and tested all controllers and models in case something was being loading without being defined.

```rb
RAILS_ENV=production rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.3 application starting in production 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
    109: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    108: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    107: from /home/andrew/workspace/kanadash/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    106: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    105: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    104: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    103: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    102: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    101: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    100: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
     99: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
     98: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
     97: from /home/andrew/workspace/kanadash/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
     96: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
     95: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
     94: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
     93: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
     92: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     91: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
     90: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     89: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
     88: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
     87: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
     86: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
     85: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
     84: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
     83: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
     82: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
     81: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
     80: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
     79: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:53:in `start'
     78: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:283:in `start'
     77: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
     76: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:27:in `app'
     75: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
     74: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
     73: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
     72: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
     71: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
     70: from config.ru:in `<main>'
     69: from config.ru:in `new'
     68: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
     67: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
     66: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
     65: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:48:in `require_relative'
     64: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
     63: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
     62: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
     61: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
     60: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     59: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
     58: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     57: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
     56: from /home/andrew/workspace/kanadash/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
     55: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
     54: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
     53: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
     52: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
     51: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
     50: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
     49: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
     48: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
     47: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
     46: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
     45: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
     44: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
     43: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
     42: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
     41: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
     40: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `each'
     39: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:356:in `eager_load!'
     38: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `eager_load!'
     37: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `each'
     36: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:477:in `block in eager_load!'
     35: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:477:in `each'
     34: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:478:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
     33: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:246:in `require_dependency'
     32: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:85:in `depend_on'
     31: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:334:in `depend_on'
     30: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:47:in `require_or_load'
     29: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
     28: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:48:in `block in require_or_load'
     27: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:356:in `require_or_load'
     26: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
     25: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:13:in `loading'
     24: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:151:in `exclusive'
     23: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:14:in `block in loading'
     22: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
     21: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:378:in `block in require_or_load'
     20: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
     19: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
     18: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
     17: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
     16: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     15: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
     14: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     13: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
     12: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.3/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb:16:in `<main>'
     11: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.3/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb:235:in `<class:Blob>'
     10: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
      9: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
      8: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
      7: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
      6: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `with_execution_control'
      5: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
      4: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `instance_eval'
      3: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.3/lib/active_storage/engine.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
      2: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/erb.rb:901:in `result'
      1: from /home/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/erb.rb:901:in `eval'
(erb):11:in `<main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I expected either the development server to not start up with eager_load true or the production server to start up with eager_load true. It's really strange eager_load works in development but not production.

Comment: I dont know where main is? I certainly have no methods named main. Any insights to where I should check?

Comment: It has nothing to do with main. Somewhere you have something like `foo[x]` where foo should be an array bit in your case its nil and `nil[0]` is not a valid code.